# ¿Qué significa el operador /=?

Tags: c#, operador

Estaba navegando en internet y me encontré este código:

```
while (n > 0)
      {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
      }
```

En sí, el código es algo irrelevante, a excepción del operador `/=`. **Qué es ese operador?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En pocas palabras, la línea de código `n/=10` vendría siendo equivalente a `n= n/10`. Estos operadores son como que versiones "cortas" de las veces cuando debes utilizar el valor de la misma variable que estás guardando, los casos comunes es con las sumas y restas (`+=` `-=`).
Pero, eso no significa que esos sean las únicas versiones cortas, menos comunes, pero existentes, están los equivalentes para multiplicación y división, entonces:

- `a += b` es equivalente a `a = a + b`
- `a -= b` es equivalente a `a = a - b`
- `a *= b` es equivalente a `a = a * b`
- `a /= b` es equivalente a `a = a / b`